# Group the Get_Items output by a single_line of text field

Tags: development, power-automate, power-platform

I have a SharePoint list with 3 columns:-

[image]

And i am getting the items based on the ExpiryDate as follow inside a scheduled workflow:-

[image]

now this will get the list items which have their expiry date within 2 weeks, 1 month & 2 months. the next thing i want to go :-

1. group the returned items by the EmailAccount
2. Build an HTML table for each EmailAccount. showing these values:-

- Expiry Date
- Item ID

so how i can group the Get_items results by the EmailAccount field?

Thanks

Comment: check [this](https://johnliu.net/blog/2018/6/do-group-by-in-flow-with-two-simple-elegant-loops) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Group-BY-in-Flow-to-send-email-of-aggregated-data/td-p/397420). let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Is this working for you now?